# Is there any existing solution to make portable ordered bit fields?

Tags: c++, bitmap

I'd like to have a way to specify bitmaps, which would look like this:

```
struct Bitmap
{
    unsigned foo: 2;
    unsigned bar: 5;
    unsigned baz: 3;
};
```

, and many similar structures, but I need the bit fields to have predictable order. But C++ doesn't guarantee any order or packing of bit fields, so I have to make some special code to implement this using bitwise operations. This could be implemented for the above structure as follows:

```
class Bitmap
{
    unsigned value;
public:
    unsigned foo() { return value&0x3; }
    unsigned bar() { return (value>>2)&0x1f; }
    unsigned baz() { return (value>>7)&0x7; }
    void set_foo(unsigned new_foo) { value=(value&~0x3)|new_foo; }
    void set_bar(unsigned new_bar) { value=(value&~(0x1f<<2))|(new_bar<<2); }
    void set_baz(unsigned new_baz) { value=(value&~(0x7<<7))|new_baz; }
    Bitmap(unsigned newFoo,unsigned newBar,unsigned newBaz)
        : value(newFoo|(newBar<<2)|(newBaz<<7))
    {}
};
```

Writing such code for many different bitmaps is a repeating task, which is why I'd like to automate it. I might use templates for this, but in that case I won't be able to name my bit fields differently for each structure (or will have to write even more code to wrap generic structure to provide the names).

Ideally I'd to have some macro to use similarly to this:

```
DEFINE_BITMAP(Bitmap,foo,2,bar,5,baz,3);
Bitmap myBits(1,9,5);
doStuff(myBits.bar());
```

where number of fields can differ between invocations of `DEFINE_BITMAP`, as can the widths.

So before I start inventing this wheel: has it already been done? If yes, what to look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I admit I underestimated this question somewhat. You indicated that you want your macro to work with a variable number of bitfield specifications. That takes a little work... but here you go.

```
/* Starting with this stuff:
 * https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms
 */

#define CAT(a, ...) PRIMITIVE_CAT(a, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PRIMITIVE_CAT(a, ...) a ## __VA_ARGS__

#define IIF(c) PRIMITIVE_CAT(IIF_, c)
#define IIF_0(t, ...) __VA_ARGS__
#define IIF_1(t, ...) t

#define COMPL(b) PRIMITIVE_CAT(COMPL_, b)
#define COMPL_0 1
#define COMPL_1 0

#define INC(x) PRIMITIVE_CAT(INC_, x)
#define INC_0 1
#define INC_1 2
#define INC_2 3
#define INC_3 4
#define INC_4 5
#define INC_5 6
#define INC_6 7
#define INC_7 8
#define INC_8 9
#define INC_9 10
#define INC_10 11
#define INC_11 12
#define INC_12 13
#define INC_13 14
#define INC_14 15
#define INC_15 16
#define INC_16 17
#define INC_17 18
#define INC_18 19
#define INC_19 20

#define DEC(x) PRIMITIVE_CAT(DEC_, x)
#define DEC_0 0
#define DEC_1 0
#define DEC_2 1
#define DEC_3 2
#define DEC_4 3
#define DEC_5 4
#define DEC_6 5
#define DEC_7 6
#define DEC_8 7
#define DEC_9 8
#define DEC_10 9
#define DEC_11 10
#define DEC_12 11
#define DEC_13 12
#define DEC_14 13
#define DEC_15 14
#define DEC_16 15
#define DEC_17 16
#define DEC_18 17
#define DEC_19 18
#define DEC_20 19

#define CHECK_N(x, n, ...) n
#define CHECK(...) CHECK_N(__VA_ARGS__, 0,)
#define PROBE(x) x, 1,

#define IS_PAREN(x) CHECK(IS_PAREN_PROBE x)
#define IS_PAREN_PROBE(...) PROBE(~)

#define NOT(x) CHECK(PRIMITIVE_CAT(NOT_, x))
#define NOT_0 PROBE(~)

#define BOOL(x) COMPL(NOT(x))
#define IF(c) IIF(BOOL(c))

/* We'll add this stuff: */

#define NUM_ARGS1(_20,_19,_18,_17,_16,_15,_14,_13,_12,_11,_10,_9,_8,_7,_6,_5,_4,_3,_2,_1, n, ...) n
#define NUM_ARGS0(...) NUM_ARGS1(__VA_ARGS__,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)
#define NUM_ARGS(...) IF(DEC(NUM_ARGS0(__VA_ARGS__)))(NUM_ARGS0(__VA_ARGS__),IF(IS_PAREN(__VA_ARGS__ ()))(0,1))

/* Something to extract things from parentheses */

#define GET_1ST(a) GET_1ST_0 a
#define GET_1ST_0(a,b) a

#define GET_2ND(a) GET_2ND_0 a
#define GET_2ND_0(a,b) b

/* And our bitfield builders */

#define BITFIELDS_MAKE_GETTER_SETTER( structname, name, bits, shift ) \
  unsigned name() const { return (value >> (shift)) & ((1U << (bits)) - 1); } \
  structname& name( unsigned field ) { value &= ~(((1U << (bits)) - 1) << (shift)); value |= field << (shift); return *this; }

#define BITFIELDS( name, ... ) CAT(BITFIELDS_,NUM_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__)) ( name, 0, __VA_ARGS__ )
#define BITFIELDS_0(  name, N )
#define BITFIELDS_1(  name, N, a                   ) BITFIELDS_MAKE_GETTER_SETTER(name, GET_1ST(a), GET_2ND(a), N)
#define BITFIELDS_2(  name, N, a,b                 ) BITFIELDS_1(name,N,a) BITFIELDS_1(name,N+GET_2ND(a),b)
#define BITFIELDS_3(  name, N, a,b,c               ) BITFIELDS_1(name,N,a) BITFIELDS_2(name,N+GET_2ND(a),b,c)
#define BITFIELDS_4(  name, N, a,b,c,d             ) BITFIELDS_1(name,N,a) BITFIELDS_3(name,N+GET_2ND(a),b,c,d)
#define BITFIELDS_5(  name, N, a,b,c,d,e           ) BITFIELDS_1(name,N,a) BITFIELDS_4(name,N+GET_2ND(a),b,c,d,e)
#define BITFIELDS_6(  name, N, a,b,c,d,e,f         ) BITFIELDS_1(name,N,a) BITFIELDS_5(name,N+GET_2ND(a),b,c,d,e,f)
#define BITFIELDS_7(  name, N, a,b,c,d,e,f,g       ) BITFIELDS_1(name,N,a) BITFIELDS_6(name,N+GET_2ND(a),b,c,d,e,f,g)
#define BITFIELDS_8(  name, N, a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h     ) BITFIELDS_1(name,N,a) BITFIELDS_7(name,N+GET_2ND(a),b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
#define BITFIELDS_9(  name, N, a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i   ) BITFIELDS_1(name,N,a) BITFIELDS_8(name,N+GET_2ND(a),b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
#define BITFIELDS_10( name, N, a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j ) BITFIELDS_1(name,N,a) BITFIELDS_9(name,N+GET_2ND(a),b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)

/* Here's our bitfield class constructor */

#define MAKE_BITFIELD_STRUCT( name, ... ) \
  struct name                        \
  {                                  \
    unsigned long long value;        \
    BITFIELDS( name, __VA_ARGS__ )   \
  }
```

Once you have that, you can use it easily enough:

```
#include <iostream>

// Define struct B { ... }
// Fields are specified left-to-right as LSB-to-MSB.
// Each field is given by its name and the number of bits it occupies.
MAKE_BITFIELD_STRUCT( Bitmap, (foo,2), (bar,5), (baz,3) );

int main()
{
  // Construct a Bitmap
  Bitmap b = Bitmap().foo(1).bar(15).baz(7);

  // Prove its worth
  std::cout << std::hex << b.value << "\n"; // produces "3bd"
}
```

There exist usable facilities in [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) to do this as well, but I find using them to be something of walking among dragons...

**Notice that the code I provided has the following limitations:**

- You can declare a maximum of 10 bitfields. If you want to use more, you'll have to update the `BITFIELDS_N` definitions (by adding more of them, up to 20).
- Each bitfield has a maximum size of an `int`, and all combined bitfields have a maximum size of a `long long int`. If you need more, consider updating the definition to use a `std::bitset`.

Notice also the named parameter idiom applied with the setters.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, now _this_ is really interesting! I'll try to completely understand it before accepting though :)

Answer (score 0):

**1) Is it possible to make portable bitfields?**

No. IMO there is no good reason why the standard leaves it to whimsy, but it is what it is.

**2) So before I start inventing this wheel: has it already been done? If yes, what to look for?**

The only suggestion I can give is to forget bitfields and just use a straight-up bitmask. There are a variety of tricks you can use to create bitmasked integers; using macro tricks is a good one. Just be careful to keep the macros contained.

For C++ stuff, you can also check out this article on [Using Enum Classes as Bitfields](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/using-enum-classes-as-bitfields.html). (I have not used it myself, but it looks cool.)

Comment: Have you read the question to the end? I didn't ask for portable C++ bitfields, I asked for the alternative macro, which would generically provide the functionality similar to the second snippet of code.

Comment: Did you read my answer to the end? You did _not_ ask for a macro -- you specifically asked what was available before you wrote your own macro -- I agreed that a macro is probably the best thing, and suggested an alternative method using enum classes, complete with a link. If you want me (or someone) to write a macro for you, you should say so in your question, but don't expect too many people eager to do that -- macros are really not that difficult. As it is, I will take the time to write up something for you that uses variable-length argument macros and post it back in a little while.